# New Firefox 70 does not open properly majority of pages. Most of them show JavaScript error "NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: javascript, firefox

Just confirmed upgrade for new Firefox 70.0. I get "Firefox is up to date" message and everything is fine. However about 70% of the pages are not shown properly.

Browser simply shows some content of those pages and hides very significant part.

For example, pages containing broadcast video player show everything but video.

On some pages navigation menu is hidden, but I still can open pages: copy URL - open it in Chrome, click an item on menu, copy URL again and open it in Firefox.

However some important sites become useless at all: I can see only some colors and text, but no functionality.

Looks like Firefox made a great security change and now most of sites using JavaScript in their code are not working.

All pages have the same error message: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Some update. I created a new profile and latest Firefox works fine. So the problem was with my profile. No doubt it happened after upgrade. I did not check very deep, but I disabled all add-ons and removed cache. It could be some settings or cookies, some damage to profile or even disabled add-ons, I don't know. I did not even try other existing profiles and was not able to fix default one.

I know only two facts: that happened to default profile and right after upgrade to 70.0,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:
On the Firefox menu go to Help -> Troubleshooting Information -> and under Give Firefox a tune up, click on Refresh Firefox.

This worked on an installation of Firefox 70.0 that was behaving as you describe.

Previously attempting to clear the cache and cookies did not work.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the profile. Couple notes for future references: only damaged profile was affected (which is great), the fix did not delete bookmark and history data. Same with cookie data. Login data was not visible for some reason, but after reload it was recovered. Add-ons were fully removed (which is also fine). Also old profile directory was added to desktop so old data can be found there if anything important was lost. Really good tool.